# time machine doesn't go back

Tags: time-machine

I enter the time machine.
I select a folder in finder.
I see red bars on the right.
If I try to click a red bar, scroll or click up/down arrows, nothing happens.
It looks like I can't go back in time. 
I tried to leave the TM open for a while. Nothing.

I tried other folders, same result.

I'm on Yosemite.
Never had problem before, but now of course, I need really the data

Comment: I experience this with a nearly full Time Machine that goes way back. Sometimes I just have to wait a long time before folders become populated. Other times I have to close Time Machine and try again. It’s a bit wobbly, but my data eventually shows up.

Comment: `time machine doesn't go back` Vote to move to physics SE.